# Как убрать \n в функции readlines() Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file.readlines():
        print(line)
```

```
test1

test2

test3

test4
```

Comment: `print(line.strip())`

Comment: @S.Nick, ты так все пробелы с обеих сторон снесёшь.

Comment: @Qwertiy в указанном примере я никаких пробелов не заметил.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Смотря что вы хотите. Можно сделать и так, чтобы не выводить никаких символов кроме тех, что были в файле:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file.readlines():
        print(line, end='')
```

Такой подход, в отличие от других ответов, ничего не убирает из строк, он просто не добавляет перевод строки при печати считанных из файла строк.

Answer (score 3):

> ```
> print(line)
> ```

```
print(line[:-1:])
```

```
print(line.rstrip('\n'))
```

Comment: Недостаток: если сверху идет пустая строка, то она остается.

Comment: @VictorsaysReinstateMonica, пустая строка и должна оставаться. А я вот про другой косяк подумал - если файл не заканчивается переводом строки, то ничего лишнего не отрежется?

Comment: во втором варианте есть проблема с системами с переводом строки по \r\n

Comment: @eri, а питон сам не заменяет в текстовом режиме как си?

Comment: @Qwertiy Думаю, @eri намекает на то, что лучше использовать `line.rstrip()`.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов, оно пробелы прибьёт - это неправильно.

Comment: @eri, под windows при открытии в текстовом режиме переводы строк будут считываться как `'\n'`, не смотря на то что в самом файле `'\n\r'`.

Answer (score 2):

Как вариант, прочитать файл целиком в строку, потом разбить ее на отдельные строки с помощью метода [`splitlines`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) (он не оставляет разделители строк, если не передать ему параметр `keepends=True`):

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file.read().splitlines():
        print(line)
```

Другой вариант (без предварительной загрузки файла целиком) - в процессе чтения к каждой строке применять  `rstrip('\n')`:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in map(lambda line: line.rstrip('\n'), file):
        print(line)
```

ну или более обычный и легче читаемый вариант:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        line = line.rstrip('\n')
        print(line)
```